# passing constructor arguments for a remote object from client program in Java

Tags: java, oop, networking, rmi, remoteobject

I have a doubt regarding RMI.
In RMI we create remote object(s) and use them to call methods as declared in the remote interface. So if I want to set some parameters of a remote object I have got to do so using some setField method ( as created ) for the object.

However since the most common way of initializing fields of an object is by the constructor of the class, can't I pass arguments from my client such that while the remote object is being created ( by new in the server ) these shall be utilized?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What makes you think, that passing arguments to a constructor is the most common way to initialize fields? I'd rather say, that *all* fields are initialized during creation of the object but only a few through constructor arguments.

Yes, fields are *initialized* while the object is created. No field value is *undefined* on an instance. But it's pretty *common*, that instance fields receive their actual values *after* the instance has been created. It's pretty common to create some default instance and set the required values later through setter methods or even with dependency injection.

Answer (score 1):

Your question doesn't make sense. The remote object has to be constructed at the server JVM and exported *before* the client can do anything with it.